# mongodb segmentation fault(11) macosx

Tags: php, mongodb

I have problem, i cant figure out, how to fix..
So i am on MacOSX machine, running php 5.3.15 version, using mongo 1.3.1 version.
When i try to execute php script, in which i try to connect to remote mongodb server, I get segmentation fault(11)..
I installed php driver with

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

I have seen, that this problem is quite popular, but havent found real solution yet..
I dont know if I am asking this question in correct stack site.. If you need anything else, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongo
sudo pecl install mongo-1.2.9
```

Solved the problem